# is there something similar to $templateCache for images?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bower

When building with gulp, there is a plugin to take html code from any source directory and embed it into a .js file and use $templatecache

the code snippet for this is

```
var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, 
    '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js'), { read: false });

gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/*.html'))

.pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
```

I was looking for something similar but for images. I have a bower component that has some image assets, but when I build my app for bower distribution, I lose the images (or the url for that image)

How do people repackage third-party assets for use in their packaged app ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check here: https://github.com/dabit3/angular-easy-image-preloader  . If you load the images in your home controller or during initialization you should not have any delays anymore.

Comment: this is not an answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You have options to:

- repackage assets by hand to your folder of images
- modify gulp/grunt (whatever) build script to copy assets from bower to your selected folder

Whatever you choose to do, at the end of day, make a sprite image (image of all images) and reference that in your styles/htmls. (sometimes you have to override some third-party styles).

Anyway hacking can't be avoided to achieve synergy. ;)